# Guide me to do recent activity web part in sharepoint 2010 using client object model

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2010

how to add the toolpart where user can specify Multiple no of sites. using client object Model get the configured site details, Show only custom list & libraries, Get only the Last 2 days created  & Modified Items details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easiest way I would suggest is to use a **Content Query WebPart** , as already it does all the filtering stuffs for you. Only things you colud do is to wire up the query to pull records of last two days. This can be done in the server site , not sure what you want to achive in Client Object Model.